# Storing JSON field using Hibernate and Oracle DB

Tags: java, json, oracle, hibernate, blob

I'm using Hibernate with Spring Boot connected to an Oracle database.
One of my Java entities is a class with a Jackson JsonNode object in it and I want to persist it in the database as a single field.
Oracle recommend that JSON is stored as a BLOB but Hibernate doesn't seem to know how to convert a JsonNode to a BLOB by default. Example entity class below:

```
@Entity    
public class MyEntity {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "blob")
  private JsonNode data;
}
```

How would you recommend I get this working? I'm assuming I need to write some sort of conversion class to convert to and from a BLOB.

Comment: Where does Oracle recommend to store it as a BLOB? Last time I checked, it was recommended to be stored as a CLOB (including a check constraint `is json`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Oracle says you save space and avoid charset conversion overhead with BLOBs. I'd use CLOB in this case, but see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/overview-of-storage-and-management-of-JSON-data.html

Comment: Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not test yet, but suppose it is the solution you want
com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.7.0

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(
     name = "json",
     typeClass = JsonBlobType.class
)

public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Type(type = "json")
    private JsonNode data;
}
```